# Has Imgur stopped giving direct links?

Tags: imgur

Has Imgur stopped giving direct file links to images uploaded?

I can't see a direct file link to this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5BeX.jpg

[image: screen shot]

(I know that the Stack Exchange website still integrates with Imgur, and gets a direct link, but I'm not asking about that.)

Comment: Some alternatives can be found here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95883/how-to-get-direct-link-of-images-on-imgur#comment98269_95883.

Comment: As an alternative, if your content is freely licensed, I would recommend uploading your photos to [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org) or [archive.org](https://archive.org/) and using them from there. These are trustworhy not-for-profits that will likely be around for a long time.

Comment: There are loads of image sharing sites. But a place like archive,org is meant to backup stuff that is important to the community of the world, timeless things to be kept long after they are gone even hopefully.  Not just a bunch of random individual's personal photos.  Anyhow imgur does provide direct links.. sometimes one has to wait a few seconds with it, too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link is in the "Share this image" menu on the right, just click "More"

[image]

Comment: Sadly, that feature has been removed.

Comment: Welp, I'll never use imgur again...

Answer (score 2):

The current solution is to  you take the link they give you e.g.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cx28.jpg  <-- not the link you ultimately want but you'll eventually get there

then in your browser get the image address e.g. in chrome right click the image and click 'copy image address'

[image]

Then you can paste the address in the browser window

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH8ti.png

The link might not come immediately - if you do it too soon it comes up as some url with the word 'blob' in it. but if you do it again i.e. having waited a moment, then it will come.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the direct link either. I found it by going to my user all images, then clicking on the image.

http://joshdance.imgur.com/all/

[image]

Which is really weird because it didn't used to be this hard.