# How to get direct link of images on Imgur?

Tags: links, images, imgur

It was possible to get the direct link some months ago but now, since Imgur was updated, I am unable to find the direct link. See:

[image: image example]

Comment: Some imgur alternatives that support direct links: https://imgoat.com, https://kek.gg, https://tinyimg.io, https://catbox.moe, https://imgtc.com, http://magaimg.net.

Comment: Sadly, none of the alternatives I mentioned seem to support CORS (imgur does).

Answer (score 26):

**Imgur does not provide a direct link to images any more**.

Still. You have a couple of **alternatives**:

#### Alternative 1

Right-click on the image and choose `Open Image in New Tab`
[image: Open Image in New Tab]
Once the image is opened, copy the image address

#### Alternative 2

Right-click on the image and choose `Copy Image Address`
[image: Copy Image Address]

#### Alternative 3

After you uploaded the image click on the little arrow on the top right corner of the image and go to `Get share links`
[image: Get share links]

Once there get the BBCode link surrounded by the `[img]` tag.
[image: the image tag]

Comment: This seems out of date.  imgur have gone out of their way to stop you having a direct image link.  They now turn images into videos and you have to embed JavaScript to post them.  It really sucks.

Comment: @Jez Funny you should say that. I just tried both of **Alternative 1** and **Alternative 2** and they work just fine. I really cannot see any issues there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something, marikamitsos. As Jez stated, imgur has gone out of its way to hide any way to direct link images. It used to be readily accessible. Option #1 posted above is no longer available.

Comment: "_Option #1 posted above is no longer available._" Sorry but **it still does work**. Please give it a try on this [link at imgur](http://imgur.com/gallery/luM2C). The answer stands up to date.

Comment: 2017 - It does work great.

Comment: @marikamitsos - That link _works_, but it is NOT a direct link. We're looking for a direct link to _just_ the image, without any of the imgur nonsense. I'll never use imgur again if they don't bring back this feature.

Comment: @jahroy Because "_That link works, but it is NOT a direct link_", you have to **apply one of the alternative solutions as desribed on the answer**, to get [the direct link](http://i.imgur.com/pqggrK0.jpg) "_to just the image, without any of the imgur nonsense_". You really do NOT need the direct link feature.

Comment: @marikamitsos - I'm on vacation and have been trying to do this on my phone. After quite a bit of time and effort, I don't believe it can be done with Safari on an iPhone. I finally tried with Chrome and it does work. Thanks :)

Comment: Works _sometimes_, tested with Chrome. I uploaded 3 images. On the first the "Copy image address" & "Open in new tab" options were available. On the 2nd uploaded image they simply were not and I had to use the BB embed option. (suggests the image was embedded as an background image, not as an actual <img>) For the third image the options again were available, but when I opened the image in a new tab the URL was https://i.imgur.com/undefined ... closed the tab, tried again, worked.

Comment: Does anyone know of a javascript library that can do this not just for imgur, but for gyfcat, giphy, youtube, etc?

Comment: There may be some confusion here because if you copy and paste the i.imgur.com/someID.someExtension link into your URL bar *and you are using a mobile browser not set to Desktop View mode*, imgur no longer serves the raw image. It still works for `a href` linking or `img src` embedding, because Imgur now checks for a HTTP referer header, which gets sent by the browser in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, this is the only method that works:

1. Upload an image to Imgur
2. If you are not logged in, be careful not to navigate away, close the tab, or refresh the tab. You will lose options that are only available to the uploader if you do so.
3. Click on the three dots, and choose "Get share links"

   [image: Screenshot]
4. Copy the "BBCode (Forums)" link

   [image: Screenshot]
5. The code will look something like this:

   ```
   [img]https://i.imgur.com/5yS6GCZ.gif[/img]
   ```

   Remove the `[img]` and `[/img]` tags, and you have the link you can use for hot-linking. Note that if you open this URL in your browser, you will be served a full web page. You need to embed the URL to an image in an `<img>` HTML tag, for instance, like this:

   ```
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5yS6GCZ.gif" alt="">
   ```

### Terms of Service

The [Imgur Terms of Service](https://imgur.com/tos) do still allow hotlinking, with these conditions:

> Don't hotlink to adult content or to file-sharing, gambling, torrent, warez, or Imgur rip-off sites. Don't impersonate someone else. Also, don't use Imgur to host image libraries you link to from elsewhere, content for your website, advertising, avatars, or anything else that turns us into your content delivery network. If you do – and we will be the judge – or if you do anything illegal, in addition to any other legal rights we may have, we will ban you along with the site you're hotlinking from, delete all your images, report you to the authorities if necessary, and prevent you from viewing any images hosted on Imgur.com. We mean it.