# How to get URL to the YouTube's advert video?

Tags: youtube, ads

Given I liked the ad video between the videos, I'd like to note the direct video address of it, so I can save and watch it again later on. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The link was visible and clickable over the video, I'm wondering why they decided to drop it and allow nerds only to check that.

Comment: When the ad is gone, is there a way to find it again? Maybe there is an HTTP request that returns a list of ads video ID based on a user preferences. I think some ad creators are using unlisted videos because I cannot find the video on YouTube by typing the ad name.

Comment: With these steps you will have the full url in less than a 30 seconds : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874062/how-to-download-video-ads-from-youtube/61716367#61716367

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While on the ad video, right click on the content and choose *Copy debug info*. Then paste the content in any textarea or editor (such as Notepad) and search for the line consisting `addocid`, `ad_debug_videoId` or `ad_docid` or  value, e.g.

```
"addocid": "AD_VIDEO_ID",
```

Once you copy the text string, you can replace it with your original video, e.g.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AD_VIDEO_ID
```

Comment: The property is now called `addocid`

Comment: Seconding what Jannis said, the property name has been updated.

Comment: Seems like it can be called `addebug_videoId` too, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on the ad video area and select *Stats for nerds* from the contextual menu.
2. Find line with the *Video ID* in the little box and copy its string value next to it.
3. Open a new tab and type in the address bar: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViDe0_1D`.

Comment: Instead of writing a second answer, please consider updating your [existing one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/113413).

Comment: Is the only difference between the two answers where you are obtaining the video ID from?

Comment: @marikamitsos These are separate answers (with different approach), so they should be voted separately.

Comment: See: [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/191655) ("When you have two distinct answers, it's better to post two different answers")

Comment: @jonsca Yes, you could say that, but I didn't see the similarities this way. For me, these are 2 different methods (only last part is similar). One method could stop working over another at some point in time, when they change something. This method is new one, and I think it wasn't available last year.

Comment: @jonsca I guess I would agree with you. Even on the post that kenorb mentions, opinions get [very diverse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice#comment52722_25210). For kenorb: Would you consider splitting [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/95898/117311) to 3 separate ones?

Comment: For readability, not necessarily, but on the other hand, if you don't split, you don't know which method/part is better/easier over another. If one method becomes outdated next year, then people start to downvote the whole answer (including the right parts), and you don't know which part is wrong (especially when people won't comment). With this approach, you know better. And I know Google likes to break things. As far as I know, [the system is designed to have separate posts for every answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28480/191655), but I can merge if mods want me to do it.

Comment: I just following the official guidances. 'Having separate solutions allows the community to vote on each according to its merits.'

Answer (score 2):

- Right Click on Video
- Copy Debug info.
- Paste it in a Text editor, Like Notepad.
- Tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for "VideoID" or "AdDocID" (Not Lower Case Sensitive).

you will find Video ID there (Lower Case Sensitive)

(ID in form of

`"addocid": "**********",`

`"addebug_videoId": "**********",`)

`,` add it to end of "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="

with this link you can go to Video directly.

"Stats for nerds" Contain same Video ID of playing AD, But it can't be copied.

Search for VideoID

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The methods above have changed.

Right click the video, copy debug code into a text editor and search for a tag that reads addebug_videoId

For example: "addebug_videoId": "xosjZoWeoIU"

So your YouTube video URL would look like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xosjZoWeoIU

This product works great by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

OK seems like a few folk are trying to do the same thing. A really cool ad you want to catch and share with your friends. Right?

1. Hit pause to stop the ad. You can't rewind or replay it
2. Right click and select "Copy debug info"
3. Paste this into a text editor (or anywhere you can edit it)
4. Search for "ad_docid" you should find a line that reads   "ad_docid": "THE ID YOU NEED",
5. Create the string: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THE ID YOU NEED
6. cut and paste this string into your browser

e.g. ad_docid reads   "ad_docid": "zoYjXvtRkIA",

copy as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoYjXvtRkIA into your browser.

Done

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, seriously, none of these worked for me... but you know what? I just paused the video on the ad and then right clicked and did "copy video url" and that url? Was the ad. So you don't have to do all this complicated stuff.

1. Pause advertisement.
2. Right click on video.
3. Choose "Copy video URL" option.
4. Paste into new tab or window.
5. Hit enter.

It legitimately worked for me just now. I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcPufDaW_nY and managed to get the URL for this advertisement https://youtu.be/EeRADNpdKD4 with this method.

Comment: Best answer.  Too bad obfuscating the domain name with a final dot no longer skips ads.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile / Android users; adding the solution here I came looking for:

- The same *debug info* / "*stats for nerds*" options exist for Youtube on the mobile site (In most versions of Chrome, and presumably most other mobile browsers)

1. Look at the normal 3 dots/bars browser menu button in the upper righthand side
2. Scroll the browser page downwards (as if to refresh the page), a **second** menu button will appear, just below
3. Tap the second Menu button, then tap Playback Settings
4. Tap Stats for Nerds
5. Dismiss the dialog menu by tapping off of it, and a video stats overlay will remain displayed
6. Copy the 11+ alphanumeric string that follows Video ID / sCPN
7. In the usual youtube link, replace the text following "watch?v= ____"

_

Regarding Megaera Vanbure's Sept 27 2020 comment to 'just Right-Click' a (desktop web) browser video. This only works on some versions/OS. Usually you get the default youtube-specific context menu options.

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive my transgression by asking for a clarification. I'm desperate for a solution.

So, same problem, but what about us mobile users on the native (Android) YouTube app? We can't right click, and the debug options are not there.

I'd really appreciate a solution if it exists. I miss the days when the menu options didn't change just for the ads, and you could just grab the vid.

Many Thanks!